# Trouble Linking when compiling a MEX file

Tags: c, matlab, compiler-errors, linker, mex

I am trying to compile a mex file that I wrote in order to run a pre-existing C program in MATLAB.  I am getting the following errors:

```
>> mex src/main.c -Iinclude -I/Users/my_name/mpfr-3.1.1/src/ -I/Users/my_name/gmp-5.0.5 -Lsrc0 -output cpdetect_c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_binomial_main", referenced from:
      _cpdetect in main.o
  "_gaussian1_main", referenced from:
      _cpdetect in main.o
  "_gaussianU_main", referenced from:
      _cpdetect in main.o
  "_mpfr_clears", referenced from:
      _cpdetect in main.o
  "_mpfr_exp10", referenced from:
      _cpdetect in main.o
  "_mpfr_inits2", referenced from:
      _cpdetect in main.o
  "_mpfr_set_d", referenced from:
      _cpdetect in main.o
  "_poisson_main", referenced from:
      _cpdetect in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am confused because these functions are all part of files that I `#Include` in my code.  How do I get the compiler to find them?

I am running MATLAB R2013a on Mac OS X 10.8 with Xcode version 4.6.3.

Thanks for any advice!

UPDATE1:

@Shai:  Contents of my src0 folder:

```
>> ls src0
Makefile            gaussian1.o         test_gaussian1.c        test_tools.c
Makefile.am         loadtraj.c          test_gaussian1_point_calc.c test_tools.o
Makefile.in         loadtraj.o          test_load           tools.c
binomial.c          main.c              test_load.c         tools.o
binomial.o          main.o              test_load.o
cpdetect            poisson.c           test_poisson.c
gaussian1.c         poisson.o           test_tools
```

This C program (originally meant to run on the command line) came from a friend and already had the src0 folder present.  I modified the code files in the 'src' folder when writing the mex function, but I didn't touch the src0 folder.

UPDATE 2: 
I realized I was pointing to the wrong location for mpfr.   I am now using the following compile command:

```
>> mex src/main.c src/binomial.c src/gaussian1.c src/gaussianU.c src/poisson.c -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include -lmpfr -output cpdetect_c
```

and it is giving the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mpfr_mul_d", referenced from:
      _gaussian1_calc_constant_part in gaussian1.o
      _gaussianU_calc_constant_part in gaussianU.o
  "_mpfr_printf", referenced from:
      _find_gaussian1_change_point in gaussian1.o
      _gaussian1_point_calc in gaussian1.o
      _gaussianU_calc_constant_part in gaussianU.o
      _find_gaussianU_change_point in gaussianU.o
      _find_poisson_change_point in poisson.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

    mex: link of ' "cpdetect_c.mexmaci64"' failed.
```

This is strange. It's not like the compiler can't find any of the mpfr functions - there are lots of others that it seems to be finding without any trouble (and if I deliberately omit the -lmpfr flag, I get a much longer list of undefined symbols).  I did confirm that mpfr_mul_d and mpfr_printf are part of the mpfr distribution I installed. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: what libraries (compiled so files) you have in 'src0' folder?

Comment: the functions you "#include", are they compiled into a shared library? where is their source code? have you compiled thier source code?

Comment: The source code for the #included functions is located in the subfolder "include" which I pointed to on the command line with '-Iinclude'.  Do I need to compile them seperately?  I thought that mex would compile any #included source automatically, along with the main function.

Comment: try `mex src/main.c src/binomial.c src/gaussian1.c src/poisson.c src/tools.c -I/Users/my_name/mpfr-3.1.1/src/ -I/Users/my_name/gmp-5.0.5 -output cpdetect_c`

Comment: @Shai: Thanks, that helped - now it found all of my source files, it is only having trouble with the mpfr functions.  How do I link to those?  I tried adding -L/Users/my_name/mpfr-3.1.1/src/ to your command above, but it didn't help.

Comment: you have to specify the library using `-l` flag do you have `.so` file in 'mpfr-3.1.1' package?

Comment: Please see my edits above for a reply.

Comment: Solution: Add the flag -L/usr/local/lib to the command line.

Comment: @dannyhmg: It looks like you are using MPFR and GMP libraries, so you should correctly specify the include and library paths as well as tell the compiler to link against them. It will be something like: `mex -largeArrayDims file.c -I/path/to/include -L/path/to/lib -lmpfr -lgmp`

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided by Amro - it is necessary to both point to the location of the library (using the flag -L/usr/local/lib in this case) and to tell the compiler to link to it (using the flag -lmpfr).  Thanks also to Shai for help troubleshooting this.